# Docker connection refused between containers

Tags: postgresql, docker, redis, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using Postgres, Redis and Node.js (adding dependencies with yarn), and trying to integrate it all with a docker-compose.yml file.

I have the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mybase
      - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypass

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: unless-stopped

  migrate:
    build: .
    entrypoint: node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate --config src/config/database.js --migrations-path src/database/migrations/
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  wavetech-be:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./:/app
    environment: 
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - DB_HOST=postgres
      - DB_USER=myuser
      - DB_PASS=mypass
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_NAME=mybase
    depends_on:
      - redis 
      - migrate
```

And the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR "/app"

COPY ./package.json ./
RUN apk add yarn
RUN yarn

COPY . .

CMD [ "yarn", "dev" ]
```

However, when I docker-compose up, I keep getting connection problems with both databases:

```
migrate_1      | 
migrate_1      | ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
migrate_1      | 
...
wavetech-be_1  | (node:85) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

Comment: You don't seem to be telling `migrate` where to find the database. Compare the environment you set up for `wavetech-be` which actually tells it where to look.

Comment: True! Thank you so much! You nailed it for the migration! That's one problem down. Any idea on the redis service, though?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be using the `REDIS_HOST`, it's still trying to connect on `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I managed to find out what the problem was: I'm using Bull with my Redis server, and even though I was passing the process.env variables through a redisConfig import, it only worked properly when I passed the process.env variables directly into the configuration of Bull. You've helped me a lot, pal. If you want to add a formal answer, I'll accept it gladly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Lucas, if you found an answer please use the "Post Your Answer" button below. Answering your own question is completely appreciated here. And we would get this question out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has two parts:

First, as pointed out by @jonrsharpe, the description of the migrate service was lacking the **environment** variables. So, as it is with the volumes, each service needs its own environment variables configured.

```
  migrate:
    build: .
    entrypoint: node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate --config src/config/database.js --migrations-path src/database/migrations/
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=postgres
      - DB_USER=myuser
      - DB_PASS=mypass
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_NAME=mybase
      - APP_PORT=3000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Second, I am using Bull to manage my Redis server. I was importing a config and passing it directly to Redis, so:

```
import redisConfig from '../../config/redis';
...
  init() {
    this.queues = Object.values(jobs).map(job => ({
      bull: new BullQueue(job.key, redisConfig),
      name: job.key,
      handle: job.handle,
    }));
  }
```

And it turns out that Bull was trying to just use the default Redis configuration. When I passed the environment variables directly into the Bull config, it worked properly:

```
  init() {
    this.queues = Object.values(jobs).map(job => ({
      bull: new BullQueue(job.key, {
        redis: {
          host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
          port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
        },
      }),
      name: job.key,
      handle: job.handle,
    }));
  }
```